# Bash Script to group multiple file by file name and archiving into one zip file and then finally moving to another dirrectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Any way to zip multiple file and should create only one zip file and move to another directory

Example :

```
/tmp/movies/
GOT1.mp4
GOT2.mp4
BREAKINGBD1.mp4
```

So I want all files having name `GOT` should be zipped in one zip file and moved to another directory(`GameOT`)

So final result:

```
/tmp/movies/
BREAKINGBD1.mp4
/tmp/movies/GameOT
GOT.zip
```

---

Right now using below code but as this script creates multiple zip file in another directory and also doesn't move the file (all the files are still present in same directory)

```
LIST_OF_FILES=*GOT*
TARGET_DIRECTORY=/tmp 
for filename in $LIST_OF_FILES; do 
    zip_filename=$filename.zip 
    zip $zip_filename $filename 
    mv $zip_filename $TARGET_DIRECTORY 
done
```

Comment: Why not simply `zip -m /tmp/movies/GameOT/GOT.zip *GOT*` ?

Comment: Also, use an array to store a list. `lst=(*GOT*); for f in "${lst[@]}"`...

Comment: @M. Nejat Aydin  this is a command right, I want a shell script

Comment: Then save that command in a file and make it a shell script.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I'm very new to bash could you please tell how to write this command in script. Indeed if I run this command manually it works. But if this command I write in script it's not working

Comment: See [Scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide#BashGuide.2FCommandsAndArguments.Scripts)

Answer (score -1):

This script will demonstrate the full functionality while creating its own test files to demonstrate.

```
#!/bin/sh

dummyInput="dummyInputFiles.list"
dirSRC="${PWD}/movies"

if [ ! -d "${dirSRC}" ]
then
    mkdir "${dirSRC}"
fi

cat>"${dummyInput}" <<EnDoFiNpUt
GOT1.mp4
GOT2.mp4
BREAKINGBD1.mp4
EnDoFiNpUt

while read line
do
    echo "${line}" >"${dirSRC}/${line}"
    sleep 1
done <"${dummyInput}"

( cd "${dirSRC}" ; ls -ltr `cat "${dummyInput}" ` )

### Locate all files matching pattern
for pattern in GOT
do
    TGT=`echo "${pattern}" | sed 's+^GO+GameO+' `
    dirZIP="${dirSRC}/${TGT}"
    if [ ! -d "${dirZIP}" ]
    then
        mkdir "${dirZIP}"
    fi

    if [ ! -d "${dirZIP}" ]
    then
        echo "\t Unable to proceed because directory "${dirZIP}" does not exist.\n" ; exit 1
    fi

    zip --quiet --display-globaldots --dot-size 1m --junk-paths --latest-time --test "${dirZIP}/${pattern}.zip" "${dirSRC}/GOT"*
done

unzip -l -v "${dirZIP}/${pattern}.zip"
```

Comment: Hey hi Eric, What if I've many files naming GOT ,BREAKINGBD. Please look my question and assume there are many files naming GOT, the functionality should be the same as posted in my question. So what would be the script to create a single zip (GOTseries.Zip) for all the files matching "GOT" in their name and then finally moving to another directory which is already present( no need to use mkdir). Thankyou

Comment: On the point of the 'mkdir', except for creating my test data to replicate your environment, the mkdir in the loop is relevant, for the scenario where  you had to rebuild your site from scratch, sometimes restore the data, but you may not always have restored what might have been manually created.  Having that logic in the code is really insignificant from CPU standpoint, but gives your logic a failsafe to recover from a condition which would break your intended workflow.

Comment: On your other points:  [1] adding "series" in the zip file name is straightforward;  [2] the name for the target directory for the zip files must be "normalized".  The mapping of "GamesOT" (Game of Thrones) is not a name mapping pattern that would work for the others (Random Assignments to suit topics) so it is best you stick to something straightforward, such as "ZIPs" (mixed upper and lower is intentional) as a standard for all,  Otherwise, you could try using "${pattern}_zips" as the normalized mapping of the pattern string to a storage directory name.

Comment: Besides, I was giving you the logic for the flow.  I wasn't handing you a full solution without you having to work for it.  This isn't a slave shop.  Your response to what is a very good start for you is probably why many people prefer to limit their input as short comments or questions, rather than expansive coding which addresses the points originally identified as the sticking points in the Question.